# Python regex replace text in quotes except quotes themselves

Tags: python, regex

So I have a test string for example

```
content = 'I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully'
```

I want to use regex to remove text in between double speech marks, but not the speech marks themselves. So it will return

```
'I opened my mouth, "" I said cheerfully'
```

I am using the following code

```
content = re.sub(r'".*"'," ",content)
```

But this removes the double speech marks aswell.
What pattern should I use to keep the speech marks but remove the text inside them.

Comment: Note that regexes can't count, so they can't match pairs. These will easily break if the content is something unbalanced like `Then the policeman said "You need to be parked less than six inches from the kerb". (That's also written as <6")`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `'""'` as the replacement string:

```
>>> content = 'I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully'
>>> content = re.sub(r'".*"', '""', content)
>>> print(content)
I opened my mouth, "" I said cheerfully
```

BTW, `.*` matches as much as possible (greedy). To match non-greedy fashion, use `.*?` or  `[^"]*`.

```
>>> content =  'I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully. "How is everyone?"'
>>> content = re.sub(r'".*?"', '""', content)
>>> print(content)
I opened my mouth, "" I said cheerfully. ""
```

Comment: Good answer! I did not see that

Comment: @RonenNess, Did you try non-greedy version in the answer? (BTW part)

Comment: @falsetru oops you are right the non-greedy one works on both cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could also use lookarounds:

```
(?<=")([^"]+)(?=")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_12YqBgsktMmqgGJ)

```
content = re.sub(r'(?<=")([^"]+)(?=")', '', content)
```

Two notes:

- `.*` will capture everything up to the *last* double-quote in your string, instead of the *next* one. This is why I've made it `[^"]+`.
- Importantly, this will not work when two doubly-quoted sub-strings are in the overall string, *unless* you increment the index at which the next search begins. So, for example, with

  I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully. "How is everyone?"

In order to *not* capture `I said cheerfully.`, you must increment the index by one after `Good morning!" is found.

Comment: should be `content = re.sub(r'(?<=")([^"]+)(?=")', '', content)`

Comment: I don't think you need the parentheses in the middle part of the expression - why not `(?<=")[^"]+(?=")` instead of `(?<=")([^"]+)(?=")` ? The `+` could be a `*`; but I suppose if the match is zero-length there is nothing to replace, so they are equivalent...

Comment: If the text is *just* going to be deleted, then the parentheses should also be deleted, as it would be a small efficiency improvement.

Comment: This almost works. But if I have 'I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully. "How is everyone?" It matches (Good morning!, I said cheerfully. , How is everyone?), where it should only match (Good morning!, How is everyone?)

Comment: @GregHornby: I wouldn't call this a flaw in the regex, rather you just need to be aware that the index must be incremented past the closing double-quote before searching again. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use "lookaround" expressions:

```
>>> content = 'I opened my mouth, "Good morning!" I said cheerfully'
>>> content = re.sub(r'(?<=").*(?=")', '', content)
```

This says "match anything that is preceded by a quote mark and followed by a quote mark".

The advantage of this method is that you can have different things in the look around - for example, you could match `(?<"|')` to match either single or double quote, and leave that quote mark alone. You can't do that if you hard wire the thing you "replaced and put back".

In the form I wrote it, this will be a "greedy" match - that is, it will match as large an expression as possible. If you have multiple pairs of quotes, you might want to use the "non greedy quantifier" `.*?` which says "stop as soon as you get a match" (i.e. stop at the next double quote). You could also explicitly match "only things that are not double quotes", i.e.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=")[^"]*(?=")', '', content)
```

Note that you still need the "end quote", so you don't end up matching everything from a single quote up to the end of the string.