# Remove New Line Feed But Only Between Quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I have the following code:

```
output = requests.get(url=url, auth=oauth, headers=headers, data=payload)
output_data = output.content

type(output_date)
<class 'bytes'>

output_data
```

> Squeezed Text (3632 Lines)

When looking at the squeezed text, I have some values that look like this:

```
Steve likes to walk his dog. Steve says to John "I like \n Pineapple, oranges, \n and pizza.\n" and then he went to bed \n.
John likes his beer cold.\n
Sally likes her teeth brushed with a bottle of jack.\n
```

How can I remove the \n characters, but ONLY if it is contained within double quotes, so that my results look like this:

```
Steve likes to walk his dog. Steve says to John "I like Pineapple, oranges, and pizza." and then he went to bed \n.
John likes his beer cold.\n
Sally likes her teeth brushed with a bottle of jack.\n
```

I know how to remove `\n` characters, but I am not sure how to do this if I only want to remove the values if they are contained within double quotes.

Here is what I have tries:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586767/python-regex-replace-text-in-quotes-except-quotes-themselves), and used this code:

```
my_text = re.sub(r'"\\n"','',my_text)
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `'"\\n"'` Your text does not contain newlines that are _directly_ surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: can you clarify? I do not understand.

Comment: `re.sub(r'"\\n"','',my_text)` This didn't work because it looks for the _exact pattern_ of double quote, followed by a newline, followed by a double quote.  Your text doesn't contain that pattern -- it has extra characters between the double quotes and the newline.

Answer (score 2):

I might be complicating it a bit, but something like this might work

```
parts = content.split("\"")
for i, part in enumerate(parts):
    if i % 2:
        parts[i] = part.replace("\n", "")
content = "\"".join(parts)
```

Comment: This is actually a very good approach. More or less what a parser would do, count the quotes and define alternating in/out groups.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

**Steps:**

> 1. Convert bytes to String
> 2. Create the pattern for Regex
> 3. Use regex to format the values.

**Step 1:**

```
my_text = my_text.decode("utf-8")
```

**Step 2:**

```
pattern = re.compile(r'".*?"',re.DOTALL)
```

**Step 3:**

```
my_text = pattern.sub(lambda x:x.group().replace('\n',''),my_text)
```

This solves my problem.